# Apache POI Workbook writes strange characters to OutputStream

Tags: java, excel, file-io, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to write from a Spring application to an Excel file (following this tutorial: https://www.roytuts.com/generic-way-of-writing-data-in-excel-using-apache-poi/ . The body of my function is pretty much the same.)

My method takes an output stream to write to, a list of objects to export and a list of the column names.

```
public void writeToExcel(OutputStream outputStream, List<T> exportObjects, List<String> columns) throws NoSuchMethodException {
   ...
   workbook.write(outputStream);
   outputStream.flush();
 }
```

Then I call the method like:

```
  OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  importExportService.writeToExcel(outputStream, objects, header);
```

When debuggiging, I can see that the correct values are passed to the cells.
But the moment I've passed workbook.write(outputStream), outputStream gets this value:

```
PK |b|b|b s(P               _rels/.rels���j�0�_���8�`�Q��2�m��4[ILb��ږ���.[K
�($}��v?�I�Q.���uӂ�h���x>=��@��p�H"�~�}�   �n����*"�H�׺؁�����8�Z�^'�#�
and so on
```

So, my question is, is there something I'm missing when writing to an OutputStream? Why is this happening, instead of showing the values in the cells?

Any help or thoughts would be wildly appreciated.

Comment: The `workbook.write` writes the bytes of a `Excel` workbook file into the `OutputStream`. This are in your case the bytes of a `*.xlsx` file, which is a `ZIP` archive containing the workbook content as multiple separate `XML` files in a special directory structure. Hence the bytes start with the magic bytes `50 4B` (PK).

Comment: That makes sense, @AxelRichter. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel spreadsheets are not saved in a text format, so that's what it looks like when you try to view it as text in the debugger.

It's actually a .zip archive containing XML files.  If you save it and change the extension to `.zip`, then you'll be able to view the contents in Windows Explorer or with the zip command.